# MacOS VPN Error NO Shared Secret was Provided Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, vpn

I Face a big problem,I made a VPN for IOS Devices,it is on the appstore,it is working nicely,However i face problem with macos application,I use same codes.Same codes work for IOS Devices however they dont work for MacOS application.

The Problem says ;
No VPN shared secret was provided. Verify your settings and try reconnecting.

When i try to connect to vpn.

Code that i use for connect vpn

```
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {

    NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
    p.serverAddress =ipAddress;
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
    NSLog(@"vpn connecting to ip %@",ipAddress);


    p.username=@"vpnuser";
    p.sharedSecretReference = [KeyChainHelper load:sharedSecret];
    p.passwordReference = [KeyChainHelper load:password];
   // NSData * data = [self searchKeychainCopyMatching:sharedSecret];

    p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;




    [NEVPNManager sharedManager].protocolConfiguration=p;

    NSMutableArray *rules = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NEOnDemandRuleConnect *connectRule = [NEOnDemandRuleConnect new];
    [rules addObject:connectRule];
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setOnDemandRules:rules];
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN Fire"];


    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];


    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Save VPN to preference complete");
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
        }

        NSError *startError;
        [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];

        delayStart(5)
        NSLog(@"%@",[NEVPNManager sharedManager]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[NEVPNManager sharedManager]);
        delayEnd


        if(startError) {
            NSLog(@"Start error: %@", startError.localizedDescription);
        }

    }];



}];
```

Here i put some screenshoots;

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: @jarvis12 any answer  do u have ? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `KeyChainHelper` is a wrapper for accessing the keychain. It isn't clear exactly what the `KeyChainHelper::load()` method returns, but my guess is either a *standard* reference or data.

`NEVPNProtocolIPSec::sharedSecretReference` is defined as:

> A persistent keychain reference to a keychain item containing the IKE shared secret.

You need to create a keychain item of type `kSecClassGenericPassword` to use as the shared secret, and provide a ***persistent reference*** to the keychain item. A persistent reference is critical here, as it can be stored to disk or passed between processes, which is required for `NEVPNManager` to access the shared secret and connect your VPN. Likewise for passwordReference.

You will need to use `SecItemCopyMatching` with return type `kSecReturnPersistentRef` to achieve this. Your `KeyChainHelper` class may provide a method to return the persistent reference.